# Partially transposing a CSV

Tags: perl, csv

I have a table export in CSV format, but the original table is structured in a way that is not convenient for my purposes:

```
id,step,field_name,field_value
3,0,field_3,9.43
1,6,field_1,447.74
1,0,field_1,239.09
1,3,field_3,135.84
1,5,field_2,277.33
1,1,field_2,758.71
1,6,field_2,52.14
1,6,field_4,12.24
3,2,field_4,539.89
2,0,field_5,"Smith, John"
1,2,field_4,670.92
2,1,field_3,142.95
3,2,field_2,451.72
1,1,field_3,281.1
1,4,field_2,103.95
1,6,field_3,549.54
1,6,field_5,"Doe, John"
1,2,field_1,5.34
4,0,field_2,1.32
1,7,field_1,94.85
3,1,field_1,90.43
3,2,field_3,578.68
3,2,field_5,"Roe, Jane"
1,1,field_1,5.4
2,0,field_4,507.95
```

Assuming `field_name` only takes values `field_1` through `field_5`, I need my data to look like this (final order is irrelevant):

```
id,step,field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4,field_5
1,0,239.09,,,,
1,1,5.4,758.71,281.1,,
1,2,5.34,,,670.92,
1,3,,,135.84,,
1,4,,103.95,,,
1,5,,277.33,,,
1,6,447.74,52.14,549.54,12.24,"Smith, John"
1,7,,,,,94.85
2,0,,,,507.95,"Doe, John"
2,1,,,142.95,,
3,0,,,9.43,,
3,1,90.43,,,,
3,2,,451.72,578.68,539.89,"Roe, Jane"
4,0,,1.32,,,
```

My first step was to sort the file so that I can transpose blocks of rows:

`sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -o sample.csv sample.csv`

Now I'm trying to build a Perl script to finish the job, but I'm new with Perl. Here is my (terrible) attempt:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use File::Copy;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary => 1,
    auto_diag => 1,
    eol => $/,
    always_quote => 1
}) or die 'Cannot use CSV: ' . Text::CSV->error_diag();

my $file = 'sample.csv';
my $backup = "$file.bak";
copy $file, $backup or die "Copy failed: $!";

open my $in_fh, '<', $backup or die "$backup: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $file or die "$file: $!";

my $loop = 1;
my $row = $csv->getline($in_fh);
my $next_row = $row;
while ($loop) {
    my @text = @$row[0,1]
    while (@$row[0] == @$next_row[0]) {
        my $pos substr $row[2], -1;
        @text[$pos + 1] = @$row[3];
        $row = $next_row;
        my $next_row = $csv->getline($in_fh)
    }
    $csv->print($out_fh, \@text);
}

close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work even if you have fields beyond `field_5`, although it assumes you want to sort them naturally. The data does not have to be sorted in advance; however, everything gets stored in a hash, so this will use a lot of memory if your CSV is large. I simply print to `STDOUT`, but you can easily modify it to print to a file instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Sort::Naturally;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary => 1,
    auto_diag => 1,
    eol => $/,
}) or die 'Cannot use CSV: ' . Text::CSV->error_diag();

my $fh = \*DATA;

my $header = $csv->getline($fh);

my (%data, %fields);
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    $data{ $row->[0] }{ $row->[1] }{ $row->[2] } = $row->[3];

    # Keep track of unique field names
    $fields{ $row->[2] } = 1;
}

# Order the additional columns
my @sorted = nsort keys %fields;

# Print header
$csv->print(\*STDOUT, [ $header->[0], $header->[1], @sorted ]);

foreach my $id ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data ) {
    foreach my $step ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %{ $data{$id} } ) {
        my $results = [ $id, $step, @{ $data{$id}{$step} }{ @sorted } ];
        $csv->print(\*STDOUT, $results);
    }
}

__DATA__
id,step,field_name,field_value
3,0,field_3,9.43
1,6,field_1,447.74
1,0,field_1,239.09
1,3,field_3,135.84
1,5,field_2,277.33
1,1,field_2,758.71
1,6,field_2,52.14
1,6,field_4,12.24
3,2,field_4,539.89
2,0,field_5,"Smith, John"
1,2,field_4,670.92
2,1,field_3,142.95
3,2,field_2,451.72
1,1,field_3,281.1
1,4,field_2,103.95
1,6,field_3,549.54
1,6,field_5,"Doe, John"
1,2,field_1,5.34
4,0,field_2,1.32
1,7,field_1,94.85
3,1,field_1,90.43
3,2,field_3,578.68
3,2,field_5,"Roe, Jane"
1,1,field_1,5.4
2,0,field_4,507.95
```

#### Output:

```
id,step,field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4,field_5
1,0,239.09,,,,
1,1,5.4,758.71,281.1,,
1,2,5.34,,,670.92,
1,3,,,135.84,,
1,4,,103.95,,,
1,5,,277.33,,,
1,6,447.74,52.14,549.54,12.24,"Doe, John"
1,7,94.85,,,,
2,0,,,,507.95,"Smith, John"
2,1,,,142.95,,
3,0,,,9.43,,
3,1,90.43,,,,
3,2,,451.72,578.68,539.89,"Roe, Jane"
4,0,,1.32,,,
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great and it even figures out the field names!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I would strongly recommend giving up on [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Naturally) in favor of [`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural).  The former has implementation bugs that can be observed if you try to sort the following list: `qw(1:200 2:7)`.

Comment: @Miller Looking back at the docs for Sort::Naturally, I see that "\W substrings (neither words-characters nor digits) are ignored." Thanks for pointing this out, I'll have to update my answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually say you might want to skip using Text::CSV for this, and instead just do:

```
while ( <$input_fh> ) {
    my ( $id, $step, $field_name, @field_values ) = split ( /,/ );
    print {$output_fh} "$id,$step,";
    if ( $field_name eq "field_1" ) { print {$output_fh} "," };
    if ( $field_name eq "field_2" ) { print {$output_fh} ",," };

     #etc.

    print {$output_fh} join(",", @field_values),"\n";
```

}

You could probably use a lookup table for numbers of columns for the field names, but I'm not sure it'd improve much.

Comment: You cannot split on comma, since there are quoted commas in the data.

Comment: Ah, fair point, yes. Might still need Text::CSV for parsing the input stream. Amended with a workaround given the sample data though.

Comment: Your edit doesn't properly quote fields with commas, so some rows will have extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with perl hashes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %records ;

# Build the Hash, doesn't matter if there's holes in the steps.
while ( <> ) {
  chomp;

  my ($id,$step,$field_name,@field_value) = split(",") ;
  my ($garbage, $field_number) = split("_", $field_name) ;

  $records{$id.",".$step}{$field_number} = join(",",@field_value );

}

my $line ;

foreach my $id_step (keys %records) {
    $line = "$id_step"  ;

# For every step, see if there's a value in the hash and print it, otherwise, empty field.
  for(my $field_number = 0; $field_number < 6 ; $field_number++) {
    if (exists $records{$id_step}{$field_number}) { $line = $line . "$records{$id_step}{$field_number}," ; next }
    else {
        $line = $line . ","  ;
    }
  chop $line ;
  print $line . "\n" ;
}

print "\n" ;
```

Which gives the following output when run through sort:

```
1,0,239.09,,,,
1,1,5.4,758.71,281.1,,
1,2,5.34,,,670.92,
1,3,,,135.84,,
1,4,,103.95,,,
1,5,,277.33,,,
1,6,447.74,52.14,549.54,12.24,"Doe, John"
1,7,94.85,,,,
2,0,,,,507.95,"Smith, John"
2,1,,,142.95,,
3,0,,,9.43,,
3,1,90.43,,,,
3,2,,451.72,578.68,539.89,"Roe, Jane"
4,0,,1.32,,,
```

Comment: Output doesn't match the OP's expected output. You're not generating a valid CSV; every row should have the same number of columns. There's also no indication of which field a particular value belongs to. Does `670.92` in your second row correspond to `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`, or `field_5`?

Comment: You now have too many columns in your output. You also haven't included a header row.